# CAN checksum algorithm

Tags: crc

I am trying to caclulate a checksum algorithm. D0 is CRC, D1 to D2 is data. Maybe someone can help me with algorithm for checksum calculation?

```
D0  D1  D2  D3
68  00  01  00
74  00  03  00
DD  01  01  00
C1  01  03  00
2D  02  01  00
31  02  03  00
98  03  01  00
84  03  03  00
E2  04  01  00
FE  04  03  00
57  05  01  00
4B  05  03  00
A7  06  01  00
BB  06  03  00
12  07  01  00
0E  07  03  00
53  08  01  00
4F  08  03  00
E6  09  01  00
FA  09  03  00
16  0A  01  00
0A  0A  03  00
A3  0B  01  00
BF  0B  03  00
D9  0C  01  00
C5  0C  03  00
6C  0D  01  00
70  0D  03  00
9C  0E  01  00
80  0E  03  00
```

Comment: In your title you mentioned "CAN". If you are referring to the well known [CAN-bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) have you checked it's documentation where the used CRC method is described?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more messages you could try this for reverse engineering checksums: https://github.com/laurenlabell/checksum_finder

For CRCs there's a tool called CRCRevEng which is harder to use, but can tackle CRCs.